# How to redirect user to a diferent path if token is expired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, react-router-dom

I'm making a simple site for a project, and i want to redirect player to a login page if the token is expired, but I'm not really sure how to do it properly, here's what I've tried, im using react-jwt to check the token

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', height:'100vh'}}>
      <Navbar/>
      <div style={{display:'flex', flex:1}}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element ={<LoginForm/>} />
          <Route path="/signUp" element ={<SignUpForm/>} />
          <Route path="/addMovie" element= {<AddMovie/>} />
          <Route path="/" element={isExpired(localStorage.getItem('token') ? <FilmList/> : <LoginForm/> )} />
          <Route path="/details" exact element ={<MovieDetails/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or something like

```
<Route path="/" 
render={props=>{
  if(isExpired(localStorage.getItem('token'))){
    return <Navigate to='/login'/>;
  }
  return <FilmList/>
}}
/>
```

The first one just returns nothing, and the second one gives a warning in console:

> Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This
> means it will render an with a null value by default resulting in an
> "empty" page.

Is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: What does isExpired do? Does it make a network request on each page request? Or does it do some internal calculation on whether the token is expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 gone are custom route components, and the `Route` component **must** have a valid ReactElement on the `element` prop. A function is incorrect. Your second snippet is close.

Create an `AuthWrapper` to conditionally render an `Outlet` for a nested route or a redirect.

```
const AuthWrapper = () => {
  return isExpired(localStorage.getItem('token')
    ? <Navigate to="/login" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

Wrap any routes you want to protect into a `Route` rendering the `AuthWrapper`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', height:'100vh'}}>
      <Navbar />
      <div style={{display:'flex', flex:1}}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm />} />
          <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUpForm />} />
          <Route path="/addMovie" element={<AddMovie />} />
          <Route element={<AuthWrapper />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<FilmList />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/details" element={<MovieDetails />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom`.

Fo into your `FilmList` component and in the rendering part do the following check:

```
if (isExpired(localStorage.getItem('token')){
 return <Redirect to='/login' />
}
```

before you return your 'normal' `FilmList`

FOR RRDv6 that doesn't support Redirect you can use the Navigate component:

```
if (isExpired(localStorage.getItem('token')){
 return <Navigate to='/login' replace={true} />
}
```

Comment: when i try to use <Redirect/> i get

"Attempted import error: 'Redirect' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'."

Comment: RRDv6 doesn't export a `Redirect` component.